# Generate ipset table from AS

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I need to generate ipset table with all (ipv4) subnets assigned to certain AS (ASN) number.
Do you know any Linux tool?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Done:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define AS to block
as=( AS1111
AS2222
)

# define output
output=('create block hash:net family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 1024')

# build list of subnets
for i in "${as[@]}"
do
        echo $i
        output+=(`whois -h whois.radb.net -- "-i origin $i" | grep -Eo "([0-9.]+){4}/[0-9]+" | head`)
done

# dump output to file
printf '%s\n' "${output[@]}" > /etc/sysconfig/ipset

exit 0
```